# О метафоре «вперить взгляд»

Tags: литература, метафора

*«**Вперил Онегин зоркий взгляд**:  Где, где смятенье, состраданье? Где пятна слез?.. Их нет, их нет!»*

**Какова  история этой метафоры,** кто и когда ее применил впервые?

Мне она кажется чересчур смелой, причем даже для современной литературы. Похожа **на сленг** – не хватает ей книжности, красоты, интеллигентности.  Мы же не индейцы, чтобы острыми перьями в людей кидаться.

Меня заинтересовал вопрос с сайта БВ (довольно забавного содержания) **о синонимах** для этого сочетания. http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4118375-chto-znachit-vperil-vzgljad-kakie-primery-upotreblenija.html

Действительно, вряд ли Татьяна могла бы сказать: Ну что вперился?"  Или: "Ну что вылупился?"  Да и мы так не скажем!

А как вам такой пушкинский «сленг»?  Как его воспринимали современники?  И кто же все-таки автор этого шедевра?

Comment: Ну так в словарях же есть этот глагол, с пометкой *разг.* Так что не метафора.

Comment: Не метафора? Да у нас вся разговорная речь метафорическая. Что, и разбор можете сделать (по составу, словообразовательный)?

Comment: Ну это же основное значение. И нет пометки *перен.* (переносное значение).

Comment: Просто метафору внесли в словарь, но от этого она не перестала быть метафорой по своей сути (это скрытое сравнение). Другими словами, пронзил он Татьяну взглядом, как острым пером. Уж и не знаю,  на что это похоже. Вы можете придумать?

Comment: Нет, метафора — это когда не буквально, а образно, то есть буквальное тоже должно существовать. Похоже на "устремил".

Comment: А как можно пронзить пером? Я понимаю копьем пронзить, а перо тут при чем?

Comment: Ну, это смотря каким пером. Помните у Розенбаума:  "...смотри не обломай «перо»
Об это каменное сердце".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Глагол [вперить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) = устремить взгляд (1780 год) задолго до Пушкина.
Корень тут **пер**, такой же как у глаголов **упереть** (взгляд) итд.

Answer (score 2):

**Класс! Ответ принят!**

Считайте, что это **новогодний розыгрыш**. Хотя если учесть мой "изворотливый" ум (это я вас цитирую), то, может, и не розыгрыш вовсе...

**Этимология слов «перо» и «переть»** у Черных подробно обозначена. У слова «перо» и.-е. корень  per – лететь (отсюда парить, пернатый, папоротник). У глагола «переть» начальный корень (s)per – бревно, стропило, подпорка и даже иногда  оружие.

С другой стороны, **у разговорного глагола «вперить»** в современном языке связей с глаголом «переть» не обозначено (да и суффикс И выглядит странно), а ранее существовавшие слова в др.-нем. sper (копье), sparum (дротик) напоминают остро заточенное перо.

**Ну это в качестве объяснительной записки.** Но и в комментариях участники форума не доказали мне достаточно убедительно, что это **не метафора.**

А жаль, что не метафора, так интереснее. А то упер взгляд! Скучно! А тут **пронзил взглядом, как острым пером**. Современный такой сленг.

Из словаря: **ВПЕРИТЬ**,  св. что в кого-что. Разг. Остановить на ком-, чём-л. (взгляд, глаза). В. свой взгляд в незнакомца.

Comment: Нет в словарях значения, похожего на "пронзить", такой метафоры не получается.