# Почему в глаголе "вперить" делают неправильное ударение?

Tags: фонетика

С точки зрения фонетики это проблемный глагол: пользователи вполне уверенно  **[выбирают](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4323764-vperit-kuda-padaet-udarenie.html)** вариант"впЕрить". Их начинают стыдить, цитируют классиков, но ничего не меняется. Может, с этим словом что-то **не так?**

Какое-то оно "неправильное" — ведь значение **упереть/впереть** в нем не прочитывается. Стилевая пометка **(разг.)**  непонятна: слово выглядит совершенно книжным, даже архаичным, часто ли его используют **в разговорной речи?**

Так можно ли как-то исправить ситуацию?  Или это слово будет **[обсуждаться постоянно](https://vk.com/wall-166793033_10388):** "ВперИмте... Высокая поэзия)) **Где сейчас такое услышишь**?"

Вот еще **мнение**. Монолог Чацкого.  "В науки он вперИт ум, алчущий познаний". Лучший ответ: ударение на И — вперИт. Ударение **смещено** для подчеркивания **архаичности** фамусовского общества.

**[Тема на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472837/%D0%9E-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4)**

Comment: Sharоn, значит, так удобней. Так устроен речевой аппарат. У нас ведь ещё есть другие слова с неправильном ударением.

Comment: Серж, если носитель языка знает правильное ударение, то хорошо и он молодец. А если он этого  не знает, то, скорее всего, ошибется. Потому что ударение поставлено неестественно. Мы же не говорим вклеИть, вставИть и т.д. И люди с нормальным чувством языка ошибаются, если  на знают нормы.  С нормой ничего не сделаешь, но слову надо дать нужную оценку. Изменить стилевую пометку на книжн. и перестать включать его в программу ЕГЭ и другие упражнения по правильной речи. В текстах классиков давать пояснения. Это мои предложения.

Comment: Не спорю. Согласен! Но разве ударение от этого изменится?

Comment: Ударение в слове изменить нельзя. Нужно изменить стилевую характеристику.  Это не разговорное слово, к тому же устаревающее. Модель его образования и значение не понимаются нашими современниками, в то время как все это понималось во времена Пушкина.

Comment: Я понимаю это. Но разве от этого перестанут делать ошибки?

Comment: Ошибки делать не престанут. Но не следует проблемное слово включать в современные задания по проверке грамотности речи. Это скорее задание факультативного плана.

Comment: Да, безусловно. Те, более оно дано с помет. разг.

Comment: Мы с вами согласны по части заданий.  Но вы не хотели бы изменить стилевую характеристику? Слово не выглядит разговорным, напротив, его практически не используют в речи. Кто сейчас так говорит?

Comment: Согласен. Не понимаю, почему стоит помет. разг. Вряд ли в разговорной речи это слово употребляется.

Comment: Теперь все согласны. Может, запишете кратко ответ.

Comment: Комментарий-то на ответ не тянет.

Comment: Очень даже тянет. Дело не в количестве слов, а в решении проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, в **Большом толковом словаре под редакцией Кузнецова** это слова приводится с помет. разг.
Согласиться с такой помет. трудно, тем более если обратиться к другим словарям. В **Словаре Ожегова(Словарь русского языка,С.И. Ожегов. 25-е издание, исправленное и дополненное. Под общей редакцией профессора Л.И. Скворцова)**   напр., это слово дается с помет.**(высок.устар.).**
В словаре Ушакова дсется. помет. книж.

**Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999;** дает это слово без каких-либо помет.
Лишь в **словаре Ефремовой** дается помет. **разг. сниж.**

Однако примеры, которые приведены в словарях, взяты из худ. литературы.

Это и подтверждает Корпус русского языка.

И вот скала, в оцепененьи смутном

**Вперивши взор** на землю и на небо...

- К. М. Фофанов. Каменотес : «В Японии, под небом раскаленным...» (07.1885-11.1885)*

Он рек, и некий дух повеял невидимо,

Повеял и затих, и вновь повеял мимо,

Владыку севера мгновенный хлад объял,

На царственный **порог вперил,** смутясь, он очи...

*А. С. Пушкин. «Недвижный страж дремал на царственном пороге...» (1824)*

Comment: Отличный ответ, Серж! Мне нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Бывает, что слова бывают книжные, а становятся разговорными. Ударение и значение тоже могут меняться. Разговорные не значит часто употребляемые. Но вопрос с этимологией нестандартного ударения остается.

Тайна ударения раскрывается по устаревшему значению слова

> устар. **вселить**, внушить ◆ Нет труднее, как вперить истину в глупое, но гордое сердце. Г. С. Сковорода, «Разговор, называемый Алфавит или Букварь мира», 1760–1775 гг. [НКРЯ] ◆ ...кто вперит ум в чугунную голову; кто одушевит сердце каменное? В. Т. Нарежный, «Гаркуша, малороссийский разбойник», 1825 г. [НКРЯ] ◆ Такую задачу Жозеф поставил себе с особенною целью, к которой подвел его Горданов, вперив ему мысль, что он может «устранить» Бодростина очень хитро, не сам, а чужими руками... Н. С. Лесков, «На ножах», 1870 г. [НКРЯ]

То есть ударение пошло по типу как в слове **вселИть**. Не такой уж и уникальный механизм оказывается.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, голос от меня.  В этом глаголе современным носителям языка неясно многое, а не только ударение. Так, значение корня ПЕР не угадывается,  так как неясна эта пара: впереть (самому, непереходный глагол)  и вперить (что-то куда-то, переходный глагол).  Словообразовательная схема для приставки В не предполагает перехода ударения  с основы на суффикс И: клеить — вклеить, ставить — вставить,  заселить — ВСЕЛИТЬ.

Comment: Оба переходные. Впереть бревно во двор. Вперить взор во двор. Насчет "перескока" ударения согласен, это немного опровергает теорию корня пер. Вперить не даром имеет устаревшее значение как у вселить, возможно там и значения корня было другое.

Comment: Я, наверное, такое значение имела в виду:  ВПЕРЕТЬ,   -о; вперев и впёрши; св. Разг.-сниж. 1. что. С трудом, с усилием внести, втащить тяжёлое, громоздкое. В. вещи в вагон. 2. =ВПЕРЕТЬСЯ. В. в избу.